# No hallo la solución

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, function, map, this

Estoy solucionando el siguiente ejercicio y definitivamente no doy con la solución. Agradecería si alguien me colabora o explica. Gracias!

EJERCICIO:

```
function crearClasePersona() {
  class Persona {
    constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
```

El constructor de la clase Persona recibe nombre (string), edad (integer), hobbies (array de strings), amigos (array de objetos)
Inicializar las propiedades de la persona con los valores recibidos como argumento

```
  Tu código aca:
  this.nombre= nombre;
  this.edad= edad;
  this.hobbies= hobbies;
  this.amigos= amigos;
}
```

El método 'addFriend' recibe un string 'nombre' y un entero 'edad' y debe agregar un objeto:
`{ nombre: nombre, edad: edad}` al arreglo de amigos de la persona.
No debe retornar nada.

```
//Tu código aca:
addFriend(nombre, edad) {
```

El método 'addHobby' recibe un string 'hobby' y debe agregarlo al arreglo de hobbies de la persona.
debe retornar nada.

```
// Tu código aca:

addHobby() {
```

El método 'getFriends' debe retornar un arreglo con sólo los nombres del arreglo de amigos de la persona.
Ej:

Suponiendo que la persona tiene estos amigos: `[{nombre: 'martin', edad: 31},{nombre: 'toni', edad: 33}]`
`persona.getFriends()`  debería devolver  `['martin', 'toni']`

```
//Tu código aca:
getFriends(){
```

El método 'getHobbies' debe retornar un arreglo con los hobbies de la persona
Ej:
`persona.getHobbies()` debe devolver `['correr', 'dormir', 'nadar']`

```
// Tu código aca:
getHobbies() {
```

El método 'getPromedioEdad' debe retornar el promedio de edad de los amigos de una persona
Ej:

Si la persona tuviera estos amigos:

```
{
amigos: [{
nombre: 'toni',
edad: 33,
}, {
nombre: 'Emi',
edad: 25
}]
}
```

`persona.getPromedioEdad()`  debería devolver **29** ya que  `(33 + 25) / 2 = 29`

```
Tu código aca:
getPromedioEdad() {
```

```
  return Persona;
};
```

Solo hice la primera parte, he visto que lo puedo hacer con el método .map, pero no sé como, de antemano, gracias.

**----------------------------**

Acá está todo el código propuesto por el ejercicio de seguido y lo que he intentado:

```
function crearClasePersona() {
  class Persona {
    constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {

      this.nombre= nombre;
      this.edad= edad;
      this.hobbies= hobbies;
      this.amigos= amigos;
    }

    addFriend(nombre, edad) {
         var amigo = {nombre, edad}
         this.amigos.push({amigo});
    }

    addHobby(hobby) {
         this.hobbies.push(hobby);

    }
    getFriends() {
         const transformarObjetoAmigoANombre = ((amigo) => amigo.nombre);
         const indexed = amigos.map(transformarObjetoAmigoANombre);

    }

    getHobbies() {
        **Este no he podido hacerlo de ninguna forma**
    }

    getPromedioEdad() {
        var sum = this.edad.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
        var prom = sum / this.edad.length;{
        return prom;
    }
  };

  return Persona;
}
```

Comment: Para empezar, ¿por qué creas la clase dentro de una función? ¿Así lo pide el enunciado del ejercicio? Para poder tratar de ayudarte, por favor edita la pregunta para poner todo el código en un solo espacio, tratando de crear un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sí, así lo pide el ejercicio. Vale, dame 5 mins y hago un apartado con todo el código. Gracias

Comment: Ya está compañero, está puesto de recorido al final

Comment: Sí, pero los métodos están vacíos y no muestras cómo ejecutas cada parte del ejercicio.

Comment: Es que ahí radica mi problema, no sé que poner en cada uno de los métodos, lo intenté con el .map, pero no me da solución :c

Comment: Entonces puedes poner la solución que has plantado con el método `map`? Así te podremos ayudarte mejor, ya que si no, se haría muy extenso. Y tampoco podemos solucionar tu problema al 100% ya que este foro no se trata de hacer los deberes a alguien, si no de ayudar en problemas específicos que puedan surgir.

Comment: Vale, pondré lo que he intentado hacer

Comment: Ahí lo he puesto, lo final que intenté con el método push  aver si servía pero tampoco :(

Comment: La documentación es tu mejor aliada cuando estás aprendiendo cualquier tecnología nueva :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tu código hay varios errores, voy a intentar explicarte el porque y como se podría solucionar.

Empecemos por el método **`addFriend`**

Como bien indica el código la variable `amigo` ya es un objeto, por lo cual al hacer el `push` no hay que volver a crear un nuevo objeto y en tu caso lo que hace es un objeto de otro objeto, entonces la solución seria simplemente hacer un push a la variable `amigo`

```
addFriend(nombre, edad) {
    //Mejor usar let, ya que se define solo en el contexto de la funcion
     let amigo = {nombre, edad}
     this.amigos.push(amigo);
}
```

El siguiente, **`getFriends`**, este esta casi bien, salvo por un error, te falto añadir `this` delante de la propiedad `amigos` y devolver el nuevo array con los nombres de los amigos.

```
getFriends() {
    const transformarObjetoAmigoANombre = ((amigo) => amigo.nombre);
    const indexed = this.amigos.map(transformarObjetoAmigoANombre);
    return indexed
}
```

> Para ahorrar en escribir de mas, podrías hacer `return this.amigos.map(amigo => amigo.nombre)`

Ahora vamos al mas fácil, **`getHobbies`**, en este método, lo único que deberías de hacer es devolver la propiedad hobbies de la persona, ya que por defecto `hobbies` debería ser un array.

```
getHobbies() {
    return this.hobbies
}
```

Y finalmente el método **`getPromedioEdad`** es donde mas errores tienes,

1. `this.edad.reduce`: Edad es un numero, por lo cual no puedes aplicarle la función [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) ya que solo aplica a los arrays
2. La propiedad `length` solo aplica a funciones, cadena de caracteres y arrays y `this.edad` es un numero.
3. Debes de sumar la edad de todos los amigos y luego dividirlo por la cantidad.

Dicho esto tu código final quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
getPromedioEdad() {
    return this.amigos.map(amigo => amigo.edad).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / this.amigos.length
  }
```

Finalmente tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```js
function crearClasePersona() {
    class Persona {
        constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.edad = edad;
            this.hobbies = hobbies;
            this.amigos = amigos;
        }

        addFriend(nombre, edad) {
            //Mejor usar let, ya que se define solo en el contexto de la funcion
            let amigo = {
                nombre,
                edad
            }
            this.amigos.push(amigo);
        }

        addHobby(hobby) {
            this.hobbies.push(hobby);

        }
        getFriends() {
            const transformarObjetoAmigoANombre = ((amigo) => amigo.nombre);
            const indexed = this.amigos.map(transformarObjetoAmigoANombre);
            return indexed
        }

        getHobbies() {
            return this.hobbies
        }

        getPromedioEdad() {
            return this.amigos.map(amigo => amigo.edad).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / this.amigos.length
        }
    };

    return Persona;
}
let amigos = [{
    nombre: 'toni',
    edad: 33,
}, {
    nombre: 'Emi',
    edad: 25
}]

let clasePersona = crearClasePersona()
//No tiene hobbys de momento
let persona = new clasePersona('Juan', 20, [], amigos)
//Mostramos los amigos
console.log("Los nombres de los amigos son:", persona.getFriends())
//Añadimos unos hobbys
persona.addHobby('programar')
persona.addHobby('correr')
// Mostramos los hobbys 
console.log("Los hobbys son:", persona.getHobbies())
//El promedio de la edad de los amigos
console.log("Promedio edad:", persona.getPromedioEdad())
//Añadir un nuevo amigo
persona.addFriend('Pedo', 20)
//Mostramos los amigos otra vez
console.log("Los nombres de los amigos son:", persona.getFriends())
//Y volvemos a calcular promedio de la edad de los amigos
console.log("Promedio edad:", persona.getPromedioEdad())
```

Comment: No sé como agradecerte lo mucho que me has ayudado!, entendí y a su vez están bien los ejercicios. Muchísimas gracias compañero!